# Creating a pandas dataframe by searching two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames:

The first table, [Artist-Name DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH2qT.png), has a unique identifier for each actor on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces/), with corresponding actor names.

The second table, [Movie-Cast DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA68C.png), has a unique identifier for every movie on IMDb and the top 7 billed actors/actresses for that corresponding movie (the artist codes correspond to the unique identifier for the actors from the first table).

I want to create a new Actor-Movie DataFrame, which will have the artist's name as the first column and the subsequent columns to be all of the movies that the actors have appeared in. So I want use the "nconst" from Table 1 to search each "principalCast" column for every movie in Table 2, and if the actor appears in one of the "principalCast" positions (1-7), to add the movie title that the actor appeared in to the new Actor-Movie DataFrame as a column. Ultimately, I want to have a table with lots of columns with all of the movies that artists have been a part of.

I have tried merging and pivoting the DataFrames with no success. I have also tried using itertuples with two for loops:

```
for row in actor_names.itertuples():
ldic = []
for r in movie_cast.itertuples():
    if row[1] in [r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10]]:
        ldic.append({row[1]:[].append(r[2])})
```

itertuples takes hours and yields no results (my entire movie database is >2000 rows and actor database is >8 million rows). However, the above code is the faulty logic that I am operating under.

Is there an efficient way to create a new DataFrame by using Table 1's unique actor identifier to search each "principalCast" (1-7) in Table 2? My desired output would be:

```
**primaryName     | nconst    |   movie 1    |   movie 2  | ... | movie n**

Brad Pitt         | nm0000015 | Fight Club   |   Seven    | ... | Mr&Mrs Smith

Jennifer Lawrence | nm0000109 | Mother       |Hunger Games| ... | Serena
```

No particular order for the movies, just need a database with the movies actors participated in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it.

1. Remove irrelevant columns from your first dataframe:

   ```
   actor_names.drop(['birthYear', 'deathYear'], axis=1, inplace=True)
   ```
2. Get columns names of actors from the second dataframe:

   ```
   cast_columns = [column
                   for column in movie_cast.columns
                   if column.startswith('principalCast')]
   ```
3. Run merging for every column name that we just got and leave only columns that we need:

   ```
   for cast_column in cast_columns:
       actor_names = actor_names.merge(movie_cast, 
                                       how='left',
                                       left_on='nconst', 
                                       right_on=cast_column)
       valid_columns = [column
                        for column in actor_names.columns 
                        if (column in ('nconst', 'primaryName') 
                            or column.startswith('originalTitle'))]
       actor_names = actor_names[valid_columns]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but my guess is something like this:

```
 pd.merge(actor_names, movie_cast,how='left',left_on=['nconst'], right_on = ['principalCast1','principalCast2',.....])
```

Comment: Getting a ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on). Assuming that you can't do multiple right_ons?

Comment: try it by iteration:
col_list = ['principalCast1','principalCast2',.....]
for col in col_list:
    pd.merge(actor_names, movie_cast,how='left',left_on=['nconst'], right_on = [col_list])

Comment: Still getting a dimension error: "Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)"